# Connecting multiple game controllers to Apple silicon and playing Steam games has glitchy input

Tags: security, bluetooth, games

The last few times I've tried playing multiplayer games on my M1 Mac, it has not worked.

Joystick input will trigger a single input, but not held input.  Characters will take a single step, then stop.  This has happened in multiple different games.

It is known that controllers can take a bit to work with macOS, issues are reported everywhere, with tons of "solutions" buried inside long Steam / Reddit threads.  I've tried a bunch, none have worked.  I'd like to move the discussion over to this platform because it's much better at yielding actual solutions.

Things I've tried include:

- enable / disable Steam overlay / input stuff
- adding every program / app to Security -> Bluetooth, Security -> Accessibility

I've heard this all has something to do with an Apple security update, but it supposedly happened back in 2020 and things *should* be working by now (2023).

**Has anyone found a bullet proof way to get multiple controllers to connect to Apple Silicon Macs?** I have DualShocks, but I'd really love to have a reliable solution that makes it so any controller just works.

EDIT:  Found more info.  Upon searching deeper, I've found that the best solution people have is to use different types of controllers.  It's been an issue for a long time now, and (from everything I've read) there were no comments anywhere of a person being able to connect multiple of the same type of controller and have it work.  My specific use case was local co-op.  Further testing shows single-player is just fine.

On an M1 Pro with OS 14.0, games tested include "Castle Crashers," "Lovers in a Dangerous Space Time," and "Bro Force"

Comment: Please edit to include what macOS version you are on, and probably quite importantly, what games are you experiencing issues with. "It is known that controllers generally don't work with macOS anymore, " is a bit of a generalisation. I for one use a DS4 on Sonoma on M1 Mac with no issues. Note as well, you will receive answers if possible, not a discussion. Try to describe in detail the circumstances re the problem with 'held input'. Are you trying to connect multiple controllers simultaneously, or having the same issue with controllers of different brands?

Comment: Added an edit.  I narrowed the issue down to multiple controllers of the same type being connected.  From what I could find, it has never worked.